# How to mark a property deprecated in a @typedef?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, tsdoc

I would like to mark a property (for example, `qux` below) as deprecated:

```
/**
 @typedef {object} Foo
 @property {string} bar
 @property {symbol} qux - How to deprecate it?
 @deprecated @property {symbol} qux2 - Doesn't work
 @property {symbol} qux3 @deprecated - This marks the whole of Foo as deprecated 
 */
```

I should mention, I'd like to do this in a JSDoc comment, not using TypeScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Issue#131](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc/issues/131) over at tsdoc, you can actually use `@deprecated` on properties, you just have to set it inside the object (works with JS as well).

For e.g.:

```
/**
 * Explain the interface ...
 */
export interface test {
    /**
     * Foo property
     */
    Foo: string;
    /**
     * @deprecated Use {@link test.qux2} instead.
     */
    qux: string;
    /**
     * qux2 property
     */
    qux2: string;
}
```

Results in:

[image]

---

In classes for e.g.:

```js
/**
 * Class description ...
 */
class User {
    /**
     * Holds user's name
     */
    name = "";
    /**
     * Holds user's surname
     */
    surname = "";
    /**
     * @deprecated Holds user height
     */
    height = 0;

    /**
     * constructor
     */

    constructor(name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}

const me = new User("Arslan", "Sohail Bano");
```

Results:

[image]

When using the deprecated property.
[image]

Comment: Is this somehow possible in JavaScript (so not using `interface` for example or any other TypeScript addition)

Comment: I have updated the answer with a class example, if you have something else in mind please let me know.

Comment: Thank you.. that's a good idea to use `class` instead of `@typedef`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the @deprecated tag can be only used for deprecating anything else than an entire symbol

Following the jsdoc docs this is the only way you can use @deprecated

```js
/**
 * @deprecated since version 2.0.0
 */
function old() {

}
```

https://jsdoc.app/tags-deprecated.html